# Force Laravel to use MySQL for authentication when MongoDB is set as default

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I thought by having the follwing line in `User.php` was enough. Where else do I need to modify my DB connection?

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';
```

However, when attempting to reset my password, it's throwing an error. I see it's trying to communicate with my MongoDB DB, which is my default DB.

```
strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
in /var/www/html/ocd3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php line 126 at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 
'strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given',
'/var/www/html/ocd3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php', '126', array('token' => array('_id' => object(MongoId), '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone faced this same problem here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/designate-connection-for-password-resets-table-other-than-default

Basically: password_resets table differs from users table, so I guess you must set the desired connection in the config/auth.php file:

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'CUSTOM_CONNECTION.password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```